# File option NAME is required in this CREATE/ALTER DATABASE statement. in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have .mdf and .ldf file of my database.i have try to attached that in my sql server 2008.

i wrote query like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE HRMS
ON ( FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MHI\MSSQL\DATA\HRMS.mdf' , SIZE = 2048KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
LOG ON ( FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MHI\MSSQL\DATA\HRMS.ldf' , SIZE = 1024KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO
```

but i am getting error :

**Msg 1036, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
File option NAME is required in this CREATE/ALTER DATABASE statement.
Msg 1036, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
File option NAME is required in this CREATE/ALTER DATABASE statement.**

now i tryed with this also..

```
Create database dbname 
On 
(   
Filename= 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MHI\MSSQL\DATA\HRMS.mdf',   
Filename = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MHI\MSSQL\DATA\HRMS.ldf'
)
For attach;
```

**Invalid usage of the option Filename in the CREATE/ALTER DATABASE statement.**

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE DATABASE HRMS
ON (NAME = 'HRMS', FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MHI\MSSQL\DATA\HRMS.mdf' , SIZE = 2048KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
LOG ON (NAME = 'HRMS_log', FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MHI\MSSQL\DATA\HRMS.ldf' , SIZE = 1024KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO
```

Include `NAME` in your statement, like the error message said.

Comment: dear sir,now i came to know this file was encrypted.so is ther any way to restore my .mdf file.     Ransomware

Answer (score 0):

you should Include NAME in your statement